# vaadin google map add-on: how to add custom control to Vaadin GoogleMap

Tags: vaadin

I am intending to add custom component (such as dialog, panel, toolbar,...) into Vaadin Google Map add-on from server side. After reading MapWidget.class source code in gwt-maps, I understand that I have to extend CustomControl for client-side component (override Initilize() function to return the control itself). But in VGoogleMap of add-on, I don't see anywhere to put logic of adding custom control in the map except for google map built-in controls. I am extending VGoogleMap, but the 'map' field is private so there is nothing much I can handle.

Thanks,
Chang.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the client-side behaviour of the Google Maps add-on, I'm afraid you'll have to download the source and change those private fields. The Google Maps add-on isn't designed to be very extendable on the client side.

If that sounds hard, you should think if adding server-side components around the add-on would suffice. [CustomComponent](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.customcomponent.html) should be a good choice.